# Remove last character from string captured with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, string

I need to remove the last character from a string in this command:

`sudo docker stats --no-stream 39858jf8 | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print $2}}'`

The result is `5.20%` , I need remove the `%` at the end, giving `5.20`.  Is it possibile to do this in the same command?

Comment: Voting to reopen since this is awk specific, the other you have to scroll scroll scroll (because line in general has many more options).

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Yes, with `substr()` you can do string slicing:

```
... | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)}}'
```

`length($2)` will get us the length of the second field, deducting 1 from that to strip off the last character.

**Example:**

```
$ echo spamegg foobar | awk '{print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)}'
fooba
```